# Is this sentence correct and what does 'incremental' describe?

Tags: grammar

> This study builds on our previous studies by verifying that self-control depletion does predict changes in work behaviors incremental to alternative motivation and attention mechanisms.

I have encounter this sentence in a article, and before reading the sentence I have discover several little pitfalls, I failed to understand the grammar structure and I wonder whether this sentence is complete and correct?

And if correct, what does incremental describe? **work behaviors**? **changes in work behaviors**? None of this is satisfying.

"This study builds on our previous studies by verifying that self-control depletion does predict changes in work behaviors", looks like a complete sentence, "incremental to alternative motivation and attention mechanisms" make's me confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your context (apparently academic psychology text), **incremental to** means **more than**.  The authors are saying that the theory (self-control depletion) has better predictive power than the other theories.

Comment: Thank you, @jonathanjo, Your explanation makes sense. I have search incremental to in bing.com, but no result about the phrase. Now that every thing makes sense.